# How to use 2013 iMac as second monitor with Windows 10 PC

Tags: display, imac, pc

I have a late 2013 iMac with Thunderbolt port (no mini display port) that I want to use as a second monitor for a new PC running Windows 10.

I have parallels on the iMac but no Miracast so don't seem to be able to use Target Display Mode.

Are there any cables/adapters I can use to connect the two?

Thanks.

Comment: The requirement is that your computer have a Thunderbolt port, if not, you'll need to do this via software.

Comment: Thanks a million, Allan. I had no luck with Air Parrot as my iMac wouldn't appear but Spacedesk is working to some extent. Although both screens are 27", when I move apps from Windows to the Mac, they are much bigger and unwieldy, despite changing the resolution, etc. I'll see if I can find a workaround, but thanks for this. It's the first success I've had!